# Javascript to click on href link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I got this code after searching around on stack overflow and it *should* work, but for some reason I am getting an error. I am trying to write JS that simulates a user clicking on a specific href link that has a specific ID.

This needs to work in all the major browsers (chrome, FF, IE, Safari)

here is the code:

HTML:

```
<a id="clickhere" href="http://link.com">Need to simulate user clicking on this link</a>
```

JS:

```
fireOnclick();
function fireOnclick() {
var target=document.getElementById("clickhere");
if(document.dispatchEvent) { // W3C
    var oEvent = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
    oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true,window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, target[0]);
    target[0].dispatchEvent( oEvent );
    }
else if(document.fireEvent) { // IE
    target[0].fireEvent("onclick");
    }    
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Add what is the error message?

Comment: is there a reason you can't use jquery? $("#clickhere").click() handles it and also covers cross browser cases for you

Comment: @JimDeville you're right, the ideal would be to use a framework here to handle the cross browser problems.

Comment: @JimDeville: Are you sure? Jquery's click only calls handlers that were set in jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/tYhrD/ It does not mimic a click. The link is the perfect example, since you don't set the behavior of the link with jQuery

Comment: @JuanMendes: if you add a onclick handler to the link, it fires. It is just the navigation that isn't firing (which still shows what you are saying). Odd that JQuery doesn't cause navigation though :(

Comment: No, it isn't odd. `$.click()` doesn't fire the HTML event. It fires the jQuery event. It also won't fire onclicks set as attributes, probably not even as node properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the [0] from your `target[0]` references. `getElementById` returns an element, not an array of elements. I tested in Chrome and it worked fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/vCVbA/1/

Comment: I added the jsfiddle. Their frame has the `X-Frame-Options` set to SAMEORIGIN so I made the link point to jsfiddle's home page.

Comment: Thank you! the old code was getelementsbyclass and i forgot to change the array